# Android: Cant get result for the API

Tags: java, android, api

I'm trying to get list of words from an online dictionary API, but I don't get any result showing on the emulator. On the search field I just get an html response, which seems to be strange. What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance!

This is the api url: https://owlbot.info

This is the activity:

```
public class WordListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView wordTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_list);

        try {
            URL wordUrl = ApiUtil.buildUrl("animals");
            new WordsQueryTask().execute(wordUrl);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){ Log.d("IO exception error", ex.getMessage() ); }
    }



    public class WordsQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

        private TextView textView;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

            URL searchURL = urls[0];
            String result = null;

            try{
                result = ApiUtil.getJson(searchURL);
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.e ("Error IO exception", ex.getMessage() );
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LA_searchTV_id);
            textView.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the layout activity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.WordListActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LA_MyWordsTV"
        android:layout_width="377dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="#1E425F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/MyWords"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#70D9E2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="@string/MyWords" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LA_wordListTV_Id"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="494dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LA_MyWordsTV" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LA_searchTV_id"
        android:layout_width="267dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#70D9E2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/LA_btnAdd_Id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/searchTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#B5C4BB"
        android:text="@string/LA_search"
        android:textColor="#094B50"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/LA_btnExit_Id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LA_btnExit_Id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/LA_btnAdd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/LA_btnExit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LA_btnAdd_Id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/LA_btnAdd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/LA_btnAdd" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This util class handling the api calls.

```
public class ApiUtil {
    public static final String QUERY_PARAMETER_KEY = "q" ;
    public static final String BASE_API_URL = "https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary";


    public ApiUtil() {  }

    public static URL buildUrl(String word){
        URL url = null;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_API_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath( word)
                .build();
        try {
            url = new URL(uri.toString());
HttpsURLConnection mConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                mConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token" + TOKEN);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }


    public static String getJson(URL url) throws IOException {

        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasData = scanner.hasNext();

            if (hasData){
                return scanner.next();
            } return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Error connecting", ex.toString() );
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

the output:
[image]

Comment: You are not supplying the API Token. The call to the API need to be authenticated using the token that you get once you register to the service. You can have a look to the curl example https://owlbot.info/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of wrongs:

1. creating wrong URL: append query as path with `appendPath` instead `appendQueryParameter`

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_API_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(word)
                .build();
```

2. Provide auth token in the header of request.

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token <YOUR_TOKEN>")
```

Also change this method:

```
public static String getJson(URL url) throws IOException {

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder serverResponse = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader resBuffer = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = resBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                  serverResponse.append(line);
            }
            return serverResponse.toString()
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Error connecting", ex.toString() );
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the apiUtil code and still no changes appear on the emulator. I updated the question with changes.

Comment: check the updated answer & give whitespace; Token<space>your token

Comment: Still the same. No result. Have you tried to run the app?

Comment: yes & it's working. Have you declared Internet permission in manifest file.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210797/room-for-nataraj-kr-and-user10728848

join the chat in the link